# Removing some numbers and dots in list in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to delete numbers with dots in text to do random quiz questions

Example of text:

```
1. Bezpośrednie stosowanie norm konstytucyjnych. 
2. Rodzaje i hierarchia metod wykładni prawa podatkowego. 
3. Utrata mocy obowiązującej przepisu prawa. 
4. Unormowania Konstytucji RP odnoszące się do tworzenia prawa podatkowego.
```

I've tried to use pop(), remove() and also I have tried to find some index but always I have finished with fail... It is possible to remove only first number with "." before sentence to have something like this ?

```
'Bezpośrednie stosowanie norm konstytucyjnych.'

'Rodzaje i hierarchia metod wykładni prawa podatkowego.' 

'Utrata mocy obowiązującej przepisu prawa.'

'Unormowania Konstytucji RP odnoszące się do tworzenia prawa podatkowego.'
```

Comment: `my_str.split('.', maxsplit=1)[-1]`?

Comment: Split once at dot, take the last element of the resulting list. Don't forget to strip the leading whitespace from text. or split at `'. '`

Comment: @Sayse that's not working. I must have something to find numbers from 1. to 123. and delete this and later put   ''   in some places to have this sentences ready to the list.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Because I have thought about something too to delete and put there in some places ""

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how you read them but making some assumptions:

- Each sentence begins with "n. "
- The sentences are in a list.

So the code will be:

```
sentences = ["s1", "s2", "s3"]
sentences = [s.split(". ", maxsplit=1)[1] for s in sentences]

print(sentences)
```

Or if you don't know the amount of white spaces:

```
sentences = [s.split(".", maxsplit=1)[1].strip() for s in sentences]
```

Comment: I have changed your code and fit good to my problem but... to only one sentence.    sentences = [s.split(". ", maxsplit=2)[1] for s in sentences]
print(sentences)

Comment: seems strange you need maxsplit=2, and even more strange that the list comprehension doesn't work...
Using this solutions works for me, be careful to check everything

Comment: questions = ['''
            1. Bezpośrednie stosowanie norm konstytucyjnych. 
            2. Rodzaje i hierarchia metod wykładni prawa podatkowego. 
            3. Utrata mocy obowiązującej przepisu prawa. 
            4. Unormowania Konstytucji RP odnoszące się do tworzenia prawa podatkowego.
            ''']

sentences = [s.split(". ", maxsplit=1)[1].strip() for s in questions]
print(sentences)
In case I see only one correct sentence.

Comment: You are using triple quotes, that's why.
Every sentence must be comma separated:
question = ["1. Bezpośrednie stosowanie norm konstytucyjnych.", "2. Rodzaje i hierarchia metod wykładni prawa podatkowego.", "3. Utrata mocy obowiązującej przepisu prawa", ..."]